# Run scheduled task as admin on multiple Azure VMs

Tags: windows, azure

I am running an Azure Windows VM which runs a batch file when it starts (its started from Task Scheduler).

The batch file cannot be started as SYSTEM and needs to be run as a user, so I use the VM administrator. In Task Scheduler this user shows as \. This all works fine.

My question is though - I want to be able to run many of these VMs by making a VHD of the existing VM then creating more VMs (perhaps in a ScaleSet) from that VHD.

The script needs to be run when the VM is first started AND if it is ever rebooted.

I assume though that when I do this, my start-up script will break as the MACHINE_NAME will be different for each VM.

What is a good solution for this problem?

Comment: well, use `%computername%` variable??

Comment: I don't know a great deal about Task Scheduler but I cannot see a way to use variables within a Task. However, you have given me an idea to use "runas" in the batch file that is executed. This way I could start the task with SYSTEM then use runas and %computername% in the batch file to run the actual task as the intended user. Thanks.

Comment: In fact psexec is a better option as runas cannot accept a password on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

if it started from task schedular and is a batch job, you can move it to webjobs too and schedule there. and then create as many webjobs to want of the same batch file. no need to create and maintain VMs